# No results while making precise matching using awk

Tags: unix, awk

I am having rows like this in my source file:

```
"Sumit|My Application|PROJECT|1|6|Y|20161103084527"
```

I want to make a precise match on Column 3 i.e. I do not want to use '~' operator while writing my awk command. However the command:

```
awk -F '|' '($3 ~ /'"$Var_ApPJ"'/) {print $3}' ${Var_RDR}/${Var_RFL};
```

is fetching me correct result but the command:

```
awk -F '|' '($3 == "${Var_ApPJ}") {print $3}' ${Var_RDR}/${Var_RFL};
```

fails to do so. Can anyone help in explaining why it happens and I am willing to use '==' because I do not want to match if the value is "PROJECT1" in source file.

Parameter Var_ApPJ="PROJECT"

${Var_RDR}/${Var_RFL} -> Refers to source file.

Comment: can you spot the difference between two scripts in terms of quotes used?  That's your answer.  Better to use `awk` variables though.

Comment: @karakfa If you mean to use the command in mentioned way then it didn't worked. Also I am using variables across the script so cannot specifically define it for awk. "awk -F '|' '($3 ~ /'"$Var_ApPJ"'/) {print $3}' ${Var_RDR}/${Var_RFL};"

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this part](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Options.html#Options) of documentation to know how to pass variable to awk.

Answer (score 0):

here is the problem -

try below command -

```
awk -F '|' '$3 == Var_ApPJ {print $3}' ${Var_RDR}/${Var_RFL};
```

Remove curly braces and bracket.

```
vipin@kali:~$ cat kk.txt
a 5 b cd ef gh
vipin@kali:~$ awk -v var1="5"  '$2 == var1 {print $3}' kk.txt
b
vipin@kali:~$
```

OR

```
#cat kk.txt
a 5 b cd ef gh
#var1="5"
#echo $var1
5
#awk '$2 == "'"$var1"'" {print $3}' kk.txt  ### With "{}"
b
#
#awk '$2 == "'"${var1}"'" {print $3}' kk.txt  ### without "{}"
b
#
```

Comment: You have defined the variable defined in awk itself and that is the reason you are even able to use without a "$" attached to var1. My requirement is to use the script variable. Also using "{" is a good practice(I tried not using { and it din't worked for me, see my comment on question itself), I don't think I can mark this as an answer to the question.

Comment: @Sumit - Check my new solution to this problem and let me know if it is satisfying the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative way of '==' with '~':

awk -F '|' '($3 ~ "^${Var_ApPJ}"$) {print $3}' ${Var_RDR}/${Var_RFL};